# dead simple Django file uploading not working :-((

Tags: python, django, upload

I am trying desperately to do a very simple file upload with Django, without (for now) bothering with templating & co.

My HTML is:

```
 <form 
      id="uploader" 
      action="bytes/"
      enctype="multipart/form-data" 
      method="post"
  >
      <input type="file" name="uploaded"/>
      <input type="submit" value="upload"/>
  </form>
```

My Python is (knowing it is a POST):

```
if path=="bytes/":
        if 'uploaded' in request.FILES:
            return HttpResponse("you uploaded a file")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("did not get the file")
```

I don't understand why I'm always getting the "did not get the file" message...

Can anyone help me, please???

Answer (score 6):

Try changing "`if 'uploaded' in request.FILES:`" to "`if request.FILES`".

You might want to take a look at the documentation as well; there's an example-- http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/

Comment: Sysrqb, I tried but the result is the same!
I saw the example you mentioned but I would like not to use all the templating/forms stuff, just a dead simple form.

Do you or anyone else know what sucks in my little code snippets???

Comment: That should work. You might want to post more of your code so we can help you better.